# If my tomorrow is being your yesterday = If my tomorrow is your yesterday?

Tags: meaning

*"If my tomorrow is being your yesterday,"*

*"If my tomorrow is your yesterday,"*

Are the two sentences the same meaning?

Comment: Without a context, one can only guess what either of these clauses could be trying to express, which makes it impossible to answer the question in its present form.

Comment: As presented, “is being” comes across as something like “is acting as”. Example: “Why is little Tommy raising his hands?” “Oh, he’s just being a superhero.”

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that "is being" is actually incorrect here. `If my tomorrow is your yesterday` is in Simple Present, whereas it is also possible to put the sentence in a subjunctive mood, ie. `If my tomorrow were your yesterday` or even `If my tomorrow be your yesterday`, which sounds more poetic and old-ish.

That said, I doubt that `If my tomorrow is being your yesterday` is even grammatically correct, although it is clear it wants to express the same thing as `If my tomorrow is your yesterday`.